# Как запросить координаты города с Open Street Map (OSM)?

Tags: java, openstreetmap

Хочу написать класс который обращается к OSM, передает на карту название города и берет обратно Ширину и Долготу это города.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался ?

Comment: Я не работал, но как пользователь считаю идею слегка фиговенькой, ибо оно мне даже на запрос «петербург» выдаёт «Бишкек, Аламудунский район, Чуйская область, 722162, Киргизия» /)_(\

Comment: @andreymal: насколько я понимаю, [2gis.ru](http://2gis.ru/) использует технологии OpenStreetMap, так что в умелых руках идея вполне рабочая.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: 2gis тоже использовать не приходилось, но попробую предположить, что у них там просто своя реализация поиска на основе данных OSM)

Comment: @andreymal: я сужу просто по строчке об OSM на главной странице. А если масштаб увеличить — пропадает. Наверное, там уже технология без OSM используется. Но данные у них почти наверняка свои.

Comment: Для целей получения координат города это явно перебор. В свое время видел базы координат по названиям, поищите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы написать код, работающий с OpenStreetMap, вам понадобится, как ни странно, OpenStreetMap API. Входная точка: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API

Когда вы будете этот код писать и наткнетесь на проблему, которую не сможете разрешить самостоятельно — пожалуйста, публикуйте вопрос по этой проблеме. Обязательно приложите код, опишите получаемый и сформулируйте желаемый результат.

Как совершенно верно [отмечает Владимир Мартьянов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449864/%D0%9A%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%81-open-street-map-osm/449869#comment479063_449864), вам стоит подумать о более эффективном способе решения задачи. Даже если получать данные из OSM, то можно, например, один раз получить координаты каждого города, составить таблицу и впоследствии получать данные из неё. База данных почти наверняка будет надежнее, быстрее и автономнее, чем запросы на лету.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ + совет. Буду трудиться!